# How to create Security realm in WAS

Tags: websphere, ejb-3.0, websphere-8

I am asked to test the compatibility of the system in various application servers. I have done the test in Weblogic and jBoss and it was successful.

When I am trying to deploy EJB's, I am struggling.

**I am unable to realise the same in Websphere Application Server 8.5.5.**

**For jBoss (configuration XML )**
Snippet:

```
    <security-realm name="TechSoftRealm">
        <authentication>
            <jaas name="TechSoft"/>
        </authentication>
    </security-realm>
</security-realms>
```

and the security domain is configured as

```
<security-domain name="TechSoft" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule" flag="required">
            <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/techSoftusers.properties"/>
            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/techSoftroles.properties"/>
            <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="anonymous"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

The users had roles have been configured in here. I have looked in various IBM documents, but unable to configure one properly.

Any assistance will be of greatly help.

**Error**

```
JSAS1480I: Security is not enabled because the ConfigURL property file is not set.
javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: 0x4942f000  minor code: 3591  completed: No]
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1552)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1042)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:962)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:614)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:765)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at com.temenos.adapter.common.runtime.outbound.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:30)

Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: 0x4942f000  minor code: 3591  completed: No
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1276)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1457)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1164)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1423)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1886)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1379)
at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:449)
at com.ibm.WsnBootstrap._WsnNameServiceStub.getProperties(_WsnNameServiceStub.java:38)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1549)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:83)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTCPTransportConnection.createSocket(WSTCPTransportConnection.java:313)
at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportConnectionBase.connect(TransportConnectionBase.java:357)
at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.getConnection(WSTransport.java:437)
at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportBase.getConnection(TransportBase.java:187)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.get(TransportManager.java:97)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.getConnection(GIOPImpl.java:130)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.locate(GIOPImpl.java:219)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.locate(ClientDelegate.java:1983)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate._createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:2008)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1186)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1272)
... 17 more
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @AlexandrePolozoff, I have added the error log.

Comment: This is [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124759/error-during-ejb3-call) from you. As I've already [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40131310/3701228) in other question, your client is not configured for SSL.

Comment: @Gas, This is where we I have multiple wars and things that are installed. to segregate the problem. I have created a simple ejb project and trying to deploy it.

Comment: @Gas, But after that I am getting a different Error. and I have pasted it on that Question,Please have a look at it. .

Answer (score 0):

o enable application security, administrative security must be enabled. This is by design. You can have administrative security without application security, but not the other way around.

By default WAS has administrative security enabled, when installed (unless you've changed that). The most basic configuration will use federated repository with file registry configured. You will be able to add users and groups via console. And then map your defined users to roles as you described in the comments.

In most production environments there is LDAP registry included in federtated, in that case you don't add users, as they are taken from LDAP.

Refer following:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tsec_csec2.html