# Error during EJB3 call

Tags: java, deployment, websphere, ejb-3.0, websphere-8

I have written a simple Ejb program, by looking from

http://mrbool.com/how-to-use-enterprise-java-beans-3-x-based-application-with-websphere-8-5-application-server/28063

The files are

```
package ejb3.test;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
/**
 * TODO: Document me!
 *
 * @author aprashanth
 *
 */
@Remote 
public interface ITestEJBRemoteInterface { 
    public boolean checkNames(String fsName); 
   }
```

**Implementation Class:**

```
package ejb3.test;

/**
 * TODO: Document me!
 *
 * @author aprashanth
 *
 */
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
/** * Session Bean implementation class TestEJB */ 
@Stateless 
public class TestEJB implements ITestEJBRemoteInterface { 
    List<String> moListOfNames = Arrays.asList("Kevin","Jiten","Martina","Brian");

    /** * Default constructor. */ 
    public TestEJB() { } 
    /** * Find if the passed name is present in the default list of names * * 
     * 
     * @return */ 
        public boolean checkNames(String fsName) { 
            boolean lboolNamePresent = false; 
            if(fsName != null) 
            { 
                lboolNamePresent = moListOfNames.contains(fsName); 
             } 
            return lboolNamePresent; 
            } 
        }
```

**Ejb-jar.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>TestEJB3 </display-name>
  <ejb-client-jar>TestEJB3Client.jar</ejb-client-jar>
</ejb-jar>
```

**At the client side:**

**I have created the stub using createStub.bat of IBM.and that jar is imported at the client side.**

```
package ejb31.test;

/**
 * TODO: Document me!
 *
 * @author aprashanth
 *
 */
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import ejb3.test.ITestEJBRemoteInterface;

public class TestEJBClient { 
    /** * @param args */ 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Properties props = new Properties(); 
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");

        props.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:2809");

        ITestEJBRemoteInterface loEJB =null; 
        Object lobj; try { InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props); 
        lobj = ctx.lookup("checkName"); 
        if (lobj instanceof ITestEJBRemoteInterface) { 
            loEJB = (ITestEJBRemoteInterface) lobj; 
            } 
            String lsName = "Imran"; 
            System.out.println("Is "+ lsName + " present in the list:: "+loEJB.checkNames(lsName)); 
            System.out.println("EJB run successful"); 
            } catch (NamingException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
        } 
   }
```

My project structure and the imported libraries as in the below figure:

[image]

At the WAS side, setup steps are as below:
**Port**

[image: Port]

**Installation Steps**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Lastly JndI Configuration.

[image]

When I run the client code, I get the following error.

```
JSAS1480I: Security is not enabled because the ConfigURL property file is not set.
javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: 0x4942f000  minor code: 3591  completed: No]
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1552)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1042)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:962)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:614)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:765)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at ejb31.test.TestEJBClient.main(TestEJBClient.java:27)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: 0x4942f000  minor code: 3591  completed: No
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1276)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1457)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1164)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1423)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1886)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1379)
at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:449)
at com.ibm.WsnBootstrap._WsnNameServiceStub.getProperties(_WsnNameServiceStub.java:38)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1549)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:83)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTCPTransportConnection.createSocket(WSTCPTransportConnection.java:313)
at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportConnectionBase.connect(TransportConnectionBase.java:357)
at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.getConnection(WSTransport.java:437)
at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportBase.getConnection(TransportBase.java:187)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.get(TransportManager.java:97)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.getConnection(GIOPImpl.java:130)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.locate(GIOPImpl.java:219)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.locate(ClientDelegate.java:1983)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate._createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:2008)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1186)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1272)
... 17 more
```

Note: Port and address is correct:

[image]

**Screen Shot of Security**

[image]

**New error on changing the inbound Configuration**

```
JSAS1480I: Security is not enabled because the ConfigURL property file is not set.
Exception in thread "P=818203:O=0:CT" java.lang.NullPointerException
at ejb31.test.TestEJBClient.main(TestEJBClient.java:32)
```

The war file which is deployed.

[image]

[image]

inside Client

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Inside server.jar inside war file

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this answer on IBM developerWorks](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/242042/javanetconnectexception-connect-address-is-invalid.html)?

Comment: Do you have Security turned on on your server? Add screenshot from Global security page.

Comment: @XSurgent, I did those changes and now I am getting a different error all together. I have attached it above.

Comment: @Gas I have pasted the Security Screen shot.

Comment: @Gas, Security is not enabled...

Comment: @user2900314 `NullPointerException` at line 32. I think that's the 'loEJB' object. Do you see anything on the server side logs for the invocation?

Comment: @XSurgent, Hi Sorry for the delayed response. I have checked the server side logs and it has nothing.

Comment: @XSurgent, I have pasted my ejb.war that is deployed.

Comment: @XSurgent, the stub that was created, using createStub has been placed in the class path of the client project.

Comment: @user2900314 : I'm not sure about this error. Consider asking the `NullPointerException` error as a new question so that someone else can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, you have to look better on your screenshot, as it is clearly visible that `Enable Administrative Security` **is CHECKED**.

So you either have to disable SSL in the RMI/IIOP inbound transport configuration, or properly configure your client to use SSL.

Something like this:

```
<java_install_root>/bin/java  
-classpath com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.5.0.jar:<list_of_your_application_jars_and_classes> 
-Djava.naming.provider.url=iiop://<your_application_server_machine_name> 
-Dcom.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL=file:///home/user1/ssl.client.props
-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=file:///home/user1/sas.client.props
<fully_qualified_class_name_to_run>
```

For details check the following page - [Running the IBM Thin Client for Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tcli_ejbthinclient.html)

### **UPDATE**

Now you have issue in the code. You have to use `PortableRemoteObject.narrow` for unmanaged clients.
Instead of:

```
   Object lobj; try { InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props); 
   lobj = ctx.lookup("checkName"); 
   if (lobj instanceof ITestEJBRemoteInterface) {   // <##### this is the problem
        loEJB = (ITestEJBRemoteInterface) lobj; 
   }
```

use:

```
lobj = initCtx.lookup(ejbJNDIName);
loEJB = (ITestEJBRemoteInterface)        javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(lobj , ITestEJBRemoteInterface.class);
```

For details see [How to lookup the Remote Interface of an EJB 3 without using Dependency Injection](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21414191)

Comment: I have made the changes suggested by you, I am still getting the same error. What are the other possibilities that could go wrong.

Comment: @user2900314, update your code and error in question, as the error can't be the same

Comment: You are right, dont know what went wrong. I redeployed the war and restarted the server it works fine now. Thank you Thanks a lot. :)